# How to select the smallest number?

Tags: jquery

I have the five div whith class "prise".
How to select the smallest prise, and add it to the "prise-box"?
I'm not strong in scripts, so I will be very thankful for solving this problem.

```
  <div id="price-box">

  </div> 

  <table id="table-prices">
    <tr>
      <td>Ткань</td>
      <td>Цена (грн)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="prise">1496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="prise">4496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="prise">2496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="prise">5296</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="prise">5696</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Make use of [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var array = [];
$('.prise').each(function(){array.push(+$(this).text());});
var minimum = Math.min.apply(null,array);
$('#price-box').text(minimum);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uvcH/1/)

Comment: tnx, It works!
But one more question - how to add in prise box the unit cost. so the finish result must loo like "5696 usd"

Comment: `$('#price-box').text(maximum + " usd");`

Comment: sorry, i need +2 reputation to do it

Comment: Its okay ;) @EvaNebko. Just remember me and do it when you get +2

Comment: океу) in debt will not stay

Comment: just said. You aren't required to do.

Comment: will see:)
Today I will tired you;)
Look, when i use the "Math.min.apply" it return me the min number(and its good) but when one of the class "prise" is empty - the function retun me 0. How to fix it.
againe tnx!

Comment: Doesn't the OP ask for the smallest prise?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** to get an array of text inside your `td` elements than use **[Math.max.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** to get the maximum element in retrieved array, then set it as content of your div:

```
var priceArr = $('.prise').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();    
}).get();
var highestPrice = Math.max.apply(Math, priceArr);
$('#price-box').html(highestPrice);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uvcH/)**

Comment: I'm curious why people think it's advantageous to create a temporary array of text items when such an array is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the prices, convert to numbers and compare each to find the lowest without having to create a temporary array of text items as many other answers are doing:

```
var smallestSoFar = Number.MAX_VALUE;
$("#table-prices .prise").each(function() {
    smallestSoFar = Math.min(smallestSoFar, parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
});
$("#price-box").text(smallestSoFar);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SNJwA/

Answer (score 0):

```
var smallest =0 ;
var prices = $('.prise').map(function(_, td) {
return $(td).text();
}).get();

for(var i = 0 ;i < prices.length; i+=1){
 if (prices[i] < smallest){
    smallest = prices[i] ;
  }
}
$('#price-box').html(smallest);
```

But you have to call this script